# How can you actually resurrect somebody in Anima?

Tags: magic, resurrection, anima-beyond-fantasy

As per the title - I can't seem to find a *single* spell or effect that performs a resurrection, so how *do* I perform a resurrection?

I would prefer to avoid the Arcana Exxet's spells in this question, but they are technically valid answers, as much as I'm annoyed that they entirely changed the spellcasting system.

The target of the resurrection can be assumed to have not died to a soul-destroying effect (e.g. Sever Existence - though if there are things that can cure that, I'd be interested in knowing!), but I'm interested in both resurrections *before* the target has passed into the Flow of Souls and *after* they have done so.

Comment: Are you certain that there is a way?

Comment: I'm reasonably sure that a *combination* of spells from the Essence and Creation paths could do it, but am not sure if I'm reading them right or if I'm missing something.

Comment: ...Even the spell that's actually *named Resurrection* doesn't create a replacement body?  agh why.

Comment: Could you create the replacement body with a different spell?

Comment: That's going to be *three* spells now.  Well, two if you catch the spirit before it moves on.

Comment: I think this may have to be an author-answered question.

Comment: As in you're suggesting I do it?

Comment: Yep!  You seem to have an answer (however convoluted).  No one else has an answer yet.  You'll want to wait a while before you accept your own answer (someone else *might* come up with a better one), but well-written author answers are fine - *especially* for the case where you came back after working it out for yourself.

Comment: Does it need to be specifically a spell? Are you allowing further books?

Comment: Given how death works in Anima it would be helpful to know what state the target of the resurrection is in, there is a big difference between a comrade who's fallen a few moments ago to a sword blow and someone hit by Sever Existence a decade ago.

Comment: @Lott Vanfield any method is valid.  Exxets are also valid, though we don't have the Core Exxet readily available at my table.  I'll edit in some data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I want to start by stating that in Anima injuries are generally taken pretty seriously and it is not a system where raising the dead is something easily accessible or done without heavy investment or cost, usually being more subject to a quest in and of itself. So with that in mind let us get to answering the question.

We should start with a brief summary of what generally happens when a character dies to give basis to the methods outlined below.

1. The character dies, which separates the body and the soul.
2. Their soul lingers for a duration determined by their POW.
3. They get Called to the Flow of Souls.
4. At this point the soul will slowly disperse or eventually reincarnate.

Now here is a list of potential methods, sorted by source book, each listing the situations to which they apply.

## Core book:

- *Book of Essence - Transmigrate Soul(pg.153)*: This spell is the base spell useful for putting a soul that is lingering around back into its body.  However it needs the body to be in good condition to work, therefore some other healing magic is likely needed before this can be attempted, if the damage is was severe (decapitations, crushed parts, etc) this might even require something as strong as Recreate(Creation. pg.129) to restore it to a 'good' state as determined by your GM.
- *Book of Essence - Resurrection (pg.154)*:  If a long enough period of time that the soul has been recalled to the Flow of Souls, then this is one of your options for getting it back.  It's limiting in that it does only that. You will still need some other method of putting back in a body (Such as Transmigrate Soul.)
- *Book of Essence - Lord of the Souls (pg.154)*: Just briefly mentioning this as an alternative means of putting a lot of souls into bodies with one spell.
- *Book of Necromancy - True Rise (pg.162)*: While this is not a true resurrection as it does not recall the soul it does allow a character's body, with abilities and memories intact, to come back to life.
- *Book of Necromancy - Come back from the Dead (pg.162)*: This spell I believe is the most comprehensive resurrection spell for a variety of reasons.  First and foremost not only does it call a soul back from the Flow of Souls, but it is the only spell that can return a soul that has been scattered.  In addition to this it also returns the soul to their body (or a body) if it can. (Note: this does carry the downside that the target into an undead being)
- *Summoning Invocation - XX The Judgement (pg.186)*: This ability undoes every effect within the limited range and time-frame.  This includes a character dying and even would revert a character being hit with a soul-destroying effect.

## Arcana Exxet:

- *Sub-path of Time - Undo time (pg.52)*: Briefly rewinds time in a small area, undoing events that occurred within the area/duration.  This includes returning any who died to life. This does not restore to life anyone hit by a soul destroying effect.
- *Incarnations - Real Affiny of Ruatha Synn (pg. 82)*: gains the ability 'Giver of Life" that can potentially raise a person who has died within a minute if they can pass a PhR check. (As long as some other penalties)

## Prometheum Exxet:

- *Danu, the Water of Life (pg.85)*: This Magic Potion can be used to resurrect a person once, however it it still requires to soul to be present to work.
- *Asclepius (pg.98)*: This staff has a resurrection power that works as long as the soul has not yet returned to the Flow of Souls.  However it only works once per person and can only be attempted once every 13 days.
- *Mjolnir (pg. 101)*: This hammer has a resurrection power that only works in the middle of a thunderstorm and must be done within 10 minutes of death. It also comes at great risk to the user to perform this task.

Special note: Any character unlucky enough to get hit by the *Book of Destruction Spell - Uncreation (Anima core pg. 135)* is unable to be restored by any of these methods.

There could potentially be more methods, but as far as I recall these are the only effects that explicitly bring a character back to life.

Comment: You said "True Rise" twice.

Comment: Fixed, that's what I get for copy/pasting to shortcut formatting.

Comment: Also something I don't quite think is an answer, but is something my table home-rules when we want to run less lethal campaigns is that your soul stays in your body until it is called away, and any healing that brings your body back to 0 life or higher (and restores any missing/destroyed vulnerable points) 'revives' the character, leaving them unconscious but stable.